# Failing to override the default methods

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I am basically trying to override the default valueOf(Object obj). So why is this still calling the default method and not the overridden one?

```
class Method {

    public static String valueOf(Object obj) {

      return "hey!!";

    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Method m1 = new Method();
        System.out.println(m1);

    }

}
```

o/p : Method@1de3f2d
Why am I getting this output? Why is the obj.toString() method being called without me defining it in the overridden method body?

Answer (score 0):

Object isn't an interface, it's just a class. It has default implementations that will be used, unless you override them. That way you always know that toString will return a string (even if you don't specifically implement it).

Now, the valueOf doesn't get called because you never try to call it?

```
class Method {

@Override
public static String toString() {

  return "hey!!";

}



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Method m1 = new Method();
    System.out.println(m1);

}
}
```

Should print "hey".

EDIT: *DISREGARD THIS:I think I see your problem. You are thinking about the Strings toString method, which quite correctly calls the valueOf method to determine what to print. But since Method doesn't extend String*

I do not know why you think it will call the value of method. It will instead use Objects [toString method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). Which uses the class name and hashcode to make the string.

Comment: *"Object isn't an interface, it's an abstract class"* ... nope, definitely -not- an abstract class.

Comment: *"You are thinking about the Strings toString method, which quite correctly calls the valueOf method to determine what to print."* ... nope.  Not right either.

Comment: Hm, you are right. He tried to edit my post saying linking to some documentation showing that string did that, and I didn't doublecheck (for some reason I never had a reason to check the implementation of strings tostring method). Now I have no idea why he thinks this will work.

Comment: Yes you are right...I never called the valueOf() but  won't the valueOf() be called implicitly as it is valueOf() that calls toString() and since I have overridden valueOf(), toString() should not be called IMO

Answer (score 0):

You aren't overriding the toString method, you are attempting to override the valueOf method. Which isn't a method in `Object` according to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Do this.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Hey!";
}
```

instead of your valueOf method.